# javascript checkbox in not holding its state on page reload

Tags: javascript, haml

i am new to javascript and i have written a code for checkbox in haml. Now on error i am re directing to the same page with error messages. But when it redirects to the same page again with the error message the checkbox is not remaining checked or unchecked whichever state i have give previously. Here is my code for haml and i have not written any js code for this..

```
      %th.checkbox-col
    %span.check
      = check_box_tag('select_all', 'yes', all_selected, {'data' => {'synchbox-trigger' => 'categories'}, class: 'form-nav-input' })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store the checkbox states. Like so:

```
localStorage.checkboxOne = 1;
```

When the page is accessed again, you can check the localStorage by checking the value:

```
if (parseInt(localStorage.checkboxOne) === 1) {
   document.getElementById("checkbox").checked = true;
}
```